# implementation of polynimial class implementation

Tags: c++

i have following code to implement  ADT of polynimial class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
template<class Number>
class POLY
{
public:
    int n;
     Number *a;
public:
    POLY<Number>(Number c,int N){

        a=new Number[N+1];
          n=N+1;
            a[N]=c;
             for (int i=0;i<N;i++) a[i]=0;
                }
    float eval( float x)  const {

         double t=0.0;
          for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
               t=t*x+a[i];
           return t;


    }


     friend POLY operator+(POLY &p,POLY&q){
        friend POLY operator+(POLY &p,POLY&q){

POLY t(0,p.n>q.n?p.n-1:q.n-1);
           for (int i=0;i<p.n;i++)
 t.a[i]+=p.a[i];
 for (int j=0;j<q.n;j++)
   t.a[j]+=q.a[j];

   return t;

}



     }
     friend POLY operator+(POLY &p,POLY&q){



     }

}


int main(){






     return 0;
}
```

but    does  node work following pragment

```
friend POLY operator+(POLY &p,POLY&q){

 POLY t(0,p.n>q.n?p.n-1:q.n-1);
           for (int i=0;i<p.n;i++)
 t.a[i]+=p.a[i];
 for (int j=0;j<q.n;j++)
   t.a[j]+=q.a[j];

   return t;

}
```

it has problem with reference please tell me what is wrong?
errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: polynomial, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 9/5/2010 6:00:34 PM.
1>PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\polynomial\Debug\".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\polynomial.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  polynomial.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\polynomial\polynomial\polynomial.cpp(54): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'int'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\polynomial\polynomial\polynomial.cpp(29): error C2270: '+' : modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
1>          c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\polynomial\polynomial\polynomial.cpp(54) : see reference to class template instantiation 'POLY<Number>' being compiled
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\polynomial\polynomial\polynomial.cpp(45): error C2270: '+' : modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.36
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

i  have updated code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

template<class Number>
class POLY
{
public:
    int n;
    Number *a;
public:
    POLY(Number c,int N){
        a=new Number[N+1];
        n=N+1;
        a[N]=c;
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++) a[i]=0;
    }

    float eval( float x)  const {
        double t=0.0;
        for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
            t=t*x+a[i];
        return t;
    }

    friend POLY operator+(POLY &p,POLY&q){

        POLY t(0,p.n>q.n?p.n-1:q.n-1);
        for (int i=0;i<p.n;i++)
           t.a[i]+=p.a[i];
        for (int j=0;j<q.n;j++)
           t.a[j]+=q.a[j];
        return t;
    }
     friend POLY operator*(POLY &p,POLY & q){

         POLY t(0,(p.n-1)+(q.n-1));
              for (int i=0;i<p.n;i++)
                     for (int j=0;j<q.n;j++)
                           t.a[i+j]=p.a[i] * q.a[j];
                return  t;

     }
};


int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    float p=3.0f;
    int n=10;

    POLY<int> x(1, 1),one(1,0),t=x+one,y=t;
     for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {  y=y*t;
     cout<<y<<endl;}
     cout<<y.eval(p)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

errors are

```
>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\polynomial1\polynomial1\polynomial.cpp(55): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'POLY<Number>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Number=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const signed char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(968): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>,POLY<Number>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              Number=int,
1>              _Ty=POLY<int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(186): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(192): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(199): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(206): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::_Bool)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(226): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(short)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(260): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned short)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(280): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(305): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(325): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(345): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned long)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(366): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(__int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(386): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(unsigned __int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(407): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(float)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(427): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(447): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(467): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(const void *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(487): or       'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, POLY<Number>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Number=int
1>          ]
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.82
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is your code complete ? Why the funky indentation? Why do you have TWO `operator+` EMPTY definition in your class? Why the EMPTY main? Why do the operands of `operator+` are non-const?

Comment: You have two definitions for `op+`? Also, what kind of an error are you experiencing -- compile time, linker or run time?

Comment: What does not work? Could you give us the exact code that won't compile (is someone calling `operator+`?), and the compiler error message?

Comment: And now, why to you have one `operator+` function inside another `operator+` function?

Comment: Consider shortening your question. For example, just remove the old code instead of adding new code

Answer (score 2):

`class` and `struct` declarations end with a ';'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

template<class Number>
class POLY
{
public:
    int n;
    Number *a;
public:
    POLY(Number c,int N){
        a=new Number[N+1];
        n=N+1;
        a[N]=c;
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++) a[i]=0;
    }

    float eval( float x)  const {
        double t=0.0;
        for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
            t=t*x+a[i];
        return t;
    }

    friend POLY operator+(POLY &p,POLY&q){

        POLY t(0,p.n>q.n?p.n-1:q.n-1);
        for (int i=0;i<p.n;i++)
           t.a[i]+=p.a[i];
        for (int j=0;j<q.n;j++)
           t.a[j]+=q.a[j];
        return t;
    }
};


int main(){
    POLY<int> p(5, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The above is a fixed version of your code that should compile. Your design could use some improvement though. Some suggestions:

- Learn about the rule of Big Three(copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor)
- Do not start off with a class template (if you are only beginning programming in C++)
- Initializer lists
- It's okay to `using namespace std;` in a test program but you must know about namespace pollution
- If you do a `new` you need a `delete` somewhere (and a `new ...[]` requires a `delete [] ...`) or else you leak memory
- Your code doesn't use anything either from `iostream` or `cstdlib`. Why keep them then?
- You don't need two `for` loops in your `friend op+`

Comment: no it is not fixed   if it help i am using visual c++2010 and  errors are the same

Comment: The code I posted compiles fine on VS2010 and Comeau. Can you try copy-pasting it to your editor window and build it?

Answer (score 2):

You have definitely too many `operator+()` defintions in your code:

```
 friend POLY operator+(POLY &p,POLY&q){
    friend POLY operator+(POLY &p,POLY&q){
        [...]
    }
 }
 friend POLY operator+(POLY &p,POLY&q){

 }
```

Obviously there should only be one of them.

The "problem with references" you mention probably means that you should take the parameters by `const` reference (and the operator itself should also be const):

```
POLY operator+(const POLY &p, const POLY &q) const {
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing an overloaded `operator<<` for your poly class. You see, `cout << y` just doesn't magically work. You have to define what exactly should happen here.

A couple of other suggestions:

- Use `const` whenever it makes sense. For example, it makes a lot of sense for `operator+`, `operator*` and `operator<<` as a cv qualifier for your reference arguments.
- Since you seem to be learning the language it might be very instructive to learn about how to write a copy constructor, an assignment operator and a destructor (respecting the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)). But in actual code, you would probably just use a vector as member which makes life *so* much easier as you practically don't have to do anything (w.r.t. defining your own special member functions).

Example:

```
template<class T>
struct poly
{
    std::vector<T> coeffs;

    // default ctor
    poly() {} 

    // conversion constructor (i.e. poly<int> --> poly<double>
    template<class U>
    poly(poly<U> const& p)
    : coeffs(p.coeffs.begin(),p.coeffs.end()) {}

    friend poly operator+(poly const& a, poly const& b)
    {
      ...
    }

    friend poly operator*(poly const& a, poly const& b)
    {
      ...
    }
};

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, poly<T> const& p)
{
    ....
    return os;
}
```

There! No need for custom copy ctor, assignment operator or destructor.